# How to store huge matrix by numpy and python in Normalized Cuts？

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I'm trying to implement Normalized Cuts. Input is a image and the algorithm needs  view each pixel of image as a node.

Suppose the  image size is 100*200, i have to create a numpy matrix of size (100*200,100*200) during the execution of the algorithm.

I'v tried to use sparse matrix (csr_matrix), but it didn't work.

How can i store this huge matrix?

For Normalized Cuts, is there any method which i don't need to store huge matrix and can still figure out the eigenvector of it?

Comment: What about standard functions like https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html . Sparse matrices are only for matrices with *a lot* of zero (ie. >70%, sparse). Also note that using a small dtype help to make the matrices smaller: 400 MB for uin8, 800 for half-float, 1.6 GB for float32 and 3.2 GB for float64. HDF5 can also help (AFAIK, it supports compression)